# Angular Download File giving [object Object] inside file

Tags: angular

I am trying to download .csr file from a backend URL , the response type from the backend is File.

In the Angular i am getting the data and passing into :

```
  downloadFile(data: any) {
    console.log(data);
    const blob = new Blob([data], {
      type: "application/pkcs10; charset=utf-8",
    });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    fileSaver.saveAs(blob, "certificate.csr");
  }
```

When i am opening my file its showing [object Object].

When i tried to print the response which i received from server i found this :

[image]

But, in the NETWORK tab i can see the response coming

[image]

Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this...
I think you have a problem with your Blob. I added to you the possibility to choose more formats to download.

```
downloadFile(data: any, fileType): void {

    let type = null;

    switch (fileType) {
      case 'pdf':
        type = { type: "application/pdf" }
        break;
      case 'csv':
        type = { type: 'text/csv' }
        break;
      case 'xls':
          type = { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' }
          break;
      case 'doc':
            type = { type: 'application/msword' }
            break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(data);
    let blob = new Blob([byteArray], type);
    saveAs(blob, certificate);
  }
```

You need this imports:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
```

Let me know it worked for you.